# Call and sms option in web app php

Tags: php, android, web-applications

Is is possible to launch a message compose screen from my php web app (android)? Also click to call function which directly call from the mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a php api with a specified url and then call it using HTTPUrlConnection and then you can send sms message to the specified phone number by calling http urls.

Comment: I want to open compose message screen on mobile device like apps does.

Comment: You can create your own form by using EditText and TextView and a button that is used as a submit button and when user clicked the button the onClickListener interface will be called and you can send http request using the HttpUrlConnection and the sms will be immediately send the phone number you wanted